# HOw to get dummy scrapy stuts count in scrapyd

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapyd, portia

How do i get the the "DummyStatsCollector" in scrapyd. I have studied from this link "http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html#dummystatscollector".. but there is no brief explanation about get scraped status in scrapyd.

I would like to be able to do something like curl http://localhost:6800/stats.json -d project=default -d spider=somespider and it would return {"pages_crawled": "650","pages_per_min":"342","items_scraped":"286","items_per_min":"156"}

but i am getting this error :

```html
<html>
  <head><title>404 - No Such Resource</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>No Such Resource</h1>
    <p>No such child resource.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks